# Alfresco REST API for downloading document

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to use the Afresco REST API to download a document. After some research I find out this REST API:

```
/alfresco/s/api/node/content{property}/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}
```

But I am not sure how to pass the parameters.

If my document details URL in Share is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/page/context/mine/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/7f77488a-60a0-48c3-9369-77183ccad0d2
```

What should be passed in `{property}`, `{store_type}`, `{store_id}` and `{id}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this NodeRef

```
workspace://SpacesStore/7f77488a-60a0-48c3-9369-77183ccad0d2
```

the values for parameter will be:

```
{property}: content
{store_type}: Workspace
{store_id}: spaceStore
{id}: 7f77488a-60a0-48c3-9369-77183ccad0d2
```

Details related to each parameter is already specified by Krutik.

And you should use this download url.

```
/alfresco/d/<d|a>/<workspace>/<store>/<nodeId>/<filename>
```

where `d=direct` and `a=attached`.

The `attach` or `direct` element is used to indicate whether to display the stream directly in the browser or download it as a file attachment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/s/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/19c6ddf6-afce-4afc-8d3d-b97054deb612 and it works

Answer (score 2):

You can find details of every web-script (REST API) in alfresco on below URL.

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index
```

For your API it is given as below.

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/script/org/alfresco/cmis/content.get
```

Description of parameter is as below.

```
Property   : Name of property which you want to retrieve.
store_type : Workspace Protocol
store_id   : Store Id of node
id         : Id of node.
```

Comment: Thanks...I tried http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/s/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/19c6ddf6-afce-4afc-8d3d-b97054deb612 and it works