# How to create link for document in Alfresco using Java API?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am able to create a folder and store content in it, but I have no idea how to create a link for this document.

I haven't been able to find an example or good documentation online.

Comment: thanks for giving this information

Comment: What do you mean by "create link"? Work out the matching Share URL for it? Create a public sharable URL for it? Other?

Comment: Gagravarr, link means  i want to make a link using which i want to share or download the content of document..but not geeting any idea ,by the way i am new to alfersco so if my undastanding is not proper ....then please provide me correct way....

Answer (score 2):

Of course downloading document is possible. There is a link in the UI, and the link can be generated in more then one way. Should should check the official documentation, existing web scripts and Google a bit.

[Alfresco REST API for downloading document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994308/alfresco-rest-api-for-downloading-document)